# How do you inductively prove a conditional?

Tags: logic, induction

I'm very lost here. I *thought* I understood inductive proofs, but then I was hit with this: 'Prove by induction that if n≥4, then n!≥2^n.' How should I approach solving this?

Comment: There's no conditional.  This just means it's not (necessarily) true for $n =1,2,3$. So just have you base case be $n = 4$.

Answer (score 2):

First start with the base case, i.e. show it is true for $n=4$. For the inductive case, assume $n! \geq 2^n$ and show $(n+1)! \geq 2^{n+1}$. Hint: $(n+1)! = (n+1)n!$

Don't think of this problem as a conditional, think of it as you're proving some inequality holds for all $n \geq 4$.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't proving: For every $n\in \mathbb N$; we have $n \ge 4 \implies n!\ge 2^n$.

You are proving:  For every $n \ge 4; n \in \mathbb N$; we have $n!\ge 2^n$.

Okay.... admittedly those two statements are logically equivalent but you seem to be thrown you are expected to prove a condition *within* the induction step.  And you don't need to do any such thing.  At least no more than any other induction prove.

(After all, in a "normal" induction proof, you are not proving: for all $n$ then $n\in \mathbb N\implies P(n)$; you are just proving: for all $n\in \mathbb N$ we have $P(n)$.)

Here we are simply offsetting our base case and ignoring $n =1,2,3$ (the statement just isn't true for those) and are simply offsetting you base case.

Your base case is $n=4$ and $4! = 24 \ge 2^4 = 16$.

Now in your in your induction step you probably will not refer $n \ge 4$ but even if you did, that's fine.  You *know* that is true as you are only considering natural numbers at least $4$.

Anyway indcution step: If $n=k$ and we assume $k! \ge 2^k$.  Then $(k+1)! = (k+1) k! > (k+1)2^k \ge2\cdot 2^k = 2^{k+1}$.

And that's it.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but could you please explain how you got ">(k+1)2^k≥2⋅2k=2^(k+1)" in your induction step? Thanks for your help!

Comment: What don't you get?  $(k+1)! = (k+1)k!$.  And $k! > 2^k$ so $(k+1)k! > (k+1)2^k$.  And $k+1 \ge 2$ so $(k+1)2^k \ge 2\cdot 2^k$ and $2\cdot 2^k = 2^{k+1}$.  SO by transitivity $(k+1)! > 2^{k+1}$.